# Selenium WebDriver browser abstraction

Tags: node.js, selenium

Is there a way to use the same test code for Firefox and chrome? Kind of abstraction where I can execute piece of code for all browser driver, without repeating blocks of test code for each browser driver

for example code

> var searchBox = ffDriver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));

repeats for each browser driver.

```
var assert = require('assert'),
  test = require('selenium-webdriver/testing'),
  webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  SeleniumServer = require('selenium-webdriver/remote').SeleniumServer;

var server = new SeleniumServer('selenium-server-standalone-2.39.0.jar', {
  port: 4444
});

server.start();
var ffDriver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .usingServer(server.address())
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.firefox())
  .build();

var chromeDriver = new webdriver.Builder()
  .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
  .build();
test.describe('Google Search', function () {

  test.it('should have a query box that you can type in ff', function () {
    ffDriver.get('http://www.google.com');
    var searchBox = ffDriver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));
    searchBox.sendKeys('webdriver');
    searchBox.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
      assert.equal(value, 'webdriver');
    });

    ffDriver.quit();
  });
  test.it('should have a query box that you can type in chrome', function () {

    chromeDriver.get('http://www.google.com');
    var searchBox = chromeDriver.findElement(webdriver.By.name('q'));
    searchBox.sendKeys('webdriver');
    searchBox.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
      assert.equal(value, 'webdriver');
    });

    chromeDriver.quit();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

```
var chromeDriver = //Create your chromeDriver here
var ffDriver = //Create your ffDriver here

var drivers = [chromeDriver, ffDriver];//This creates an array of all of the drivers
for (var i = 0; i< drivers.length; i++){//Run the following block of code for each driver
    var driver = drivers[i];//Assign the driver variable
    driver.get('http://www.google.com');//Use the driver variable.
    //The rest of the automation code
}
```

Note, that in the future, you are probably going to want more structure in your code, but the code above should work fine.